# Javascript Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined

Tags: javascript

It says 'Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined'
I feel im not intializing the array in the correct way please help.

```
var validationInfo = new Array();
var currentStep = 1;
validationInfo["step1"].push({ elementId: "txtsearchBar",       validateFunc: isEmpty });
validationInfo["step2"].push({ elementId: "txtdetails",         validateFunc: isEmpty });  
function isEmpty(element) {
    //alert(element);
    return $(element).val() == undefined || $(element).val() == "";
}
function isCurrentSubmissionValid(stepId) {
    var isOK = true;
    alert(validationInfo);
    for (var i = 0; i < validationInfo[stepId].length; i++) {
        var element = $("#" + validationInfo[i].elementId);
        var validationFunction = validationInfo[i].validateFunc;
        if (!validationFunction(element)) {
            element.addClass("has-error").removeClass("has-success");
            isOK = false;
        } else
        {
            element.addClass("has-success").removeClass("has-error");
        }
    }
    return isOK;
}
```

Comment: `validationInfo["step1"]` is undefined... similarly the other one... You need to create validationInfo as an Object

Comment: What if i define it above as var validationInfo = ["step1", "step2"] will then the push function work?

Comment: @SmokeyDawson Still the same error..

Comment: @AshishRanjan Can you please show an example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create validationInfo as an Object not an Array

```js
var validationInfo = {step1: [], step2: [] };
validationInfo['step1'].push("haha");
validationInfo['step2'].push("hehe");

console.log(validationInfo)
```

In your loop, I believe you have to do similar change, for example:

```
validationInfo[stepId][i].elementId
```

assuming `stepId` is one of `step1` or `step2`. Wen you access `validationInfo[i]`, you are accessing keys like: `0, 1 ,2, etc` in the `validationInfo`. Those are the indexes of your `step1` or `step2` arrays..

Comment: Well it did work but i want to push objects and it throws and error 'Cannot read property 'elementId' of undefined.'

Answer (score 0):

As you can not pass the key when you use push method in javascript, you can try this.

```
validationInfo.push({ value: { elementId: "txtsearchBar", validateFunc: isEmpty }, index: 'step1'});
```

Answer (score 0):

you should write `define _this = this;` in head, then replace all `this` of `_this`

Comment: this is suit for vue